# Flutter - How to set the widget size by implicitly match other's?

Tags: flutter

I have a parent widget containing two widgets. The first widget has the default width set wrapping it's content. I want the second widget to have the same width, implicitly. For example,

```
Row(children: [Text('...'), W])
```

On `build`, when the `Text` get it's width, W will have the same too, or at least I can afford to have to update it after, just like something equivalent to this Javascript.

```
e.style.width = o.offsetWidth
```

I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57115690/how-to-size-a-widget-in-row-based-on-other-widgets), unfortunately the asker asked the wrong question inviting the wrong answer.

Comment: With https://pub.dev/packages/boxy, you can write pretty much any layout algorithm you want.  It's turning off the autopilot, but sometimes hand-flying is ok, especially on landings. :)

Comment: Also, I presume you are really saying "divide the available width for the whole row equally", in which case, just put expandeds with the same flex value around both.

Comment: @RandalSchwartz tq i'll take a look